# Allow Google Chrome to access location from local server

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation

I am trying to create a HTML/Javascript website using notepad++ with geolocation features. However, google chrome has blocked my current location tracking as I run from `file:///` how can I enable the access?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a local web server (e.g. http://localhost/)?

Comment: @TasosK how can I do so? I usually just select run > launch in chrome!

Comment: Take a look here [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) if in Windows or [LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) if in Linux.

Comment: yeah I installed WAMP! but how will I link it to notepad++?

Comment: In http://www.wampserver.com/en/ there are instructions on using WAMP. Files in c:\wamp\www are served by Apache

Comment: @TasosK. aight will check it out! thank you so much :-)

Comment: @TasosK.: My reason is 'too much work if it can be avoided'. ☺